# Advantages / disadvantages of using a bitwise enum?

Tags: c#

Context: Database normalization, I am creating a table: `UserInvolvement`.
There are many ways (based on roles and other ways) a `User` can be involved in another entity: `Foo`. In the current situation each type of involvement was added on the Foo table as a separate column, that holds the reference to a User. But this type of storage went short, when multiple users were supposed to have the same type of involvement in Foo.

They decided to store that FK to the Users as a CSV in that involvement column. Yes OMG! I can't believe it either.

So now I am creating the `UserInvolvement` table:

- FooID
- UserID
- Involvement

Involvement will be an Enumerator in code.

**Now my question is:**
Should I just create a normal enumerator? 
Or should I use a bitwise enum?

If I choose a bitwise enum: I can make the `FooID` and `UserID` combination unique. And on a small scale it will reduce the total amount of records in this table. Also a User either has a type of involvement in Foo or not. It's boolean. There is no such thing as having the same type of involvement multiple times.

The challenge I see: This does require that I always 'translate' the Involvement using bitwise operations to check the actual Involvement. How do I implement this in the Data Access Layer using EF? And when I delete a users involvement, I should update the bitwise value. Unless no flags remain, then it should be deleted.

Are there any other implications I am overlooking?
So finally: **what is the best choice? A normal Enum or a bitwise enum?**

Comment: You can store a max of 30 flags within a 32 bits integer right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that Flags (bitwise enum) can include more than one State at once.

If you have a Rating system you could use Flags

```
[Flags] public enum Rating {
    Normal    = 0,   // 00000000
    Great     = 1,   // 00000001
    Super     = 2,   // 00000010
    Mega      = 4,   // 00000100
    Legendary = 8    // 00001000
}
```

Flags checking for bits. Take attention to this fact.

Normal Enums dont take care about this effect. Each Enum is unique

```
public enum State{
    Normal    = 0,
    Great     = 1,
    Super     = 2,
    Mega      = 3,
    Legendary = 4
}
```

Now you can check for one `State` only, not for multiple `States`.

In your case for UserRoles you could use the Flags, because the Admin will have the permission of the `User`and the `Moderator` and so on.

```
[Flags] public enum Role{
    None      = 0,    // 00000000
    View      = 1,    // 00000001
    Write     = 2,    // 00000010
    Execute   = 4,    // 00000100
}
```

You can define the `permutation` in the class definition as

```
[Flags] public enum Role{
    None      = 0,                   // 00000000
    View      = 1,                   // 00000001
    Write     = 2,                   // 00000010
    Execute   = 4,                   // 00000100
    ViewWrite = (View | Write)       // 00000011
    ViewExecute = (View | Execute)   // 00000101
    WriteExecute = (Write | Exectue) // 00000110
    All = (View | Write | Exectue)   // 00000111
}
```

or in the code:

```
Role role = Role.View | Role.Write;
```

[Here you can find a great article about what to use.](http://hugoware.net/blog/enums-flags-and-csharp)

Comment: I will take this as a yes, use flags answer. I will accept your answer and just see where it will take me.

Comment: This is totally the wrong way to set the values of a flags enum. They should use powers of two. [See the Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) which clearly states that you should `define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap. `

Comment: @MatthewWatson: 100% correct. I already knew this. I only accepted his answer based on the fact that he tells me to go ahead and use the bitwise enum. The values should indeed always be in powers of two.

Comment: @MatthewWatson oh, yeah you are right. I missunderstood the definition of `flags` no i know, that in this case i would need to define `Admin = (User | Moderator)`. Sorry for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i also added the definition of the `permutation`, which i missunderstood

Comment: Don't forget to undo the downvote on my question! ;-)

Comment: I did not downvote anythin, my answer got downvoted as well, but i dont know who did this ^^

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf I didn't downvote anything, I just didn't upvote. :) Not sure why your question was downvoted tho.

Comment: Would be great to know how I would check what roles are assigned. Thanks!